# Can I use IP addresses to limit API access

Tags: api, jsonp

I have a mini API that is only for an app I have built. The API service is on a separate domain to my app. I make jsonp calls to it and receive json in return.

Therefore I only want my app to be able to access it. Can I just list a series of IP addresses for my app and allow them? Is there a better way to stop requests from anyone else to my API?

Comment: there is more then one solution, all dependable on the way your infrastructure is setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to implement IP-based filtering would be at the web-server level. Here's a brief introduction to [access control with Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html). If that happens to be your web-server.

Answer (score 1):

If the IP stays the same throughout time, yes this is a valid idea. Another way would be with an id and a key, if you expect further usage from other (dynamic) ip adresses.

Answer (score 1):

What operating system is the API service running on? If it's Linux, look into [iptables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) to only allow a certain IP to access a specific port.